# Butterworth BP filtering in C/C++, strange spectrum

Tags: c, filtering, signal-processing, fft, octave

I got a Bw BP C code from here, https://www-users.cs.york.ac.uk/~fisher/mkfilter, as commented in other OS topics, and made a 250Hz, 4th order, passing from 10 to 20Hz.

Below is the code of this filter, adapted from the code provided at this site, and added the lines to multiply the real and imaginary parts of the input signal (coming from a fw FFT R2C):

```
const unsigned char NZEROS = 8,
                    NPOLES = 8;
double              GAIN = 1.121655430e+02,
                    xv[NZEROS + 2] = {},        // NZEROS + 1 for real and + 1 for imag
                    yv[NPOLES + 2] = {};        // NPOLES + 1 for real and + 1 for imag

for (size_t i = 0; i < array_length_fft_1D; i++)
    {
    xv[0] = xv[1];  xv[1] = xv[2];
    xv[2] = xv[3];  xv[3] = xv[4];
    xv[4] = xv[5];  xv[5] = xv[6];
    xv[6] = xv[7];  xv[7] = xv[8];
    xv[8] = fft_complex_1D[0][i] / GAIN;        // Real part, input
    xv[9] = fft_complex_1D[1][i] / GAIN;        // Imaginary part, input

    yv[0] = yv[1];  yv[1] = yv[2];
    yv[2] = yv[3];  yv[3] = yv[4];
    yv[4] = yv[5];  yv[5] = yv[6];
    yv[6] = yv[7];  yv[7] = yv[8];

    // Multiplying the real part
    yv[8] = (xv[0] + xv[8]) - 4 * (xv[2] + xv[6]) + 6 * xv[4]
        + (-0.1316807150 * yv[0]) + (1.2338753102 * yv[1])
        + (-5.2054087885 * yv[2]) + (12.8890751850 * yv[3])
        + (-20.5097097890 * yv[4]) + (21.4961146820 * yv[5])
        + (-14.4728919700 * yv[6]) + (5.7005626010 * yv[7]);

    // Multiplying the imaginary part
    yv[9] = (xv[0] + xv[9]) - 4 * (xv[2] + xv[6]) + 6 * xv[4]
        + (-0.1316807150 * yv[0]) + (1.2338753102 * yv[1])
        + (-5.2054087885 * yv[2]) + (12.8890751850 * yv[3])
        + (-20.5097097890 * yv[4]) + (21.4961146820 * yv[5])
        + (-14.4728919700 * yv[6]) + (5.7005626010 * yv[7]);

    fft_complex_1D[0][i] = static_cast<float>(yv[8]);       // At this point the real part of the complex array is overwritten
    fft_complex_1D[1][i] = static_cast<float>(yv[9]);       // At this point the imaginary part of the complex array is overwritten
    }
```

fft_complex_1D is the input array coming from the fw FFT, which at the end of each iteration has the real and imaginary parts multiplied by the coefficients. It is later sent to the inverse FFT C2R and it outputs a float array.

Then, when I go to Octave to plot the spectrum and see if things are really being filtered, frequencies just before 10Hz and just after 20Hz are attenuated, but then everything else seems untouched, where I expected attenuation. See the figure below which shows the 10-20Hz region marked green. Blue is input, unfiltered data (real numbers from -5 to +5). Red is the filtered data. No scaling was applied to any data.

[image: Frequency spectrum plot]

There is something wrong or missing in this filter code. Can you guys provide some feedback (no pun intended)?

Comment: I am going to direct you to a different stack exchange. https://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Are you applying the filter to the frequency domain data? The filter is intended to be applied to the time domain data, isn't it?

Comment: @mtrw I am not sure. As I haven't seen any application of it made public, nor explicit notes on "how" to use it, then I had to try and see.

Comment: Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a `main()` function and at least one `#include`. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem (including any necessary inputs, but preferably not needing any), then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

Comment: @TobySpeight Apologies if I didn't explain along the original post. What I included was just the filtering section. The rest of the program was omitted because it is in this part that things provide incorrect results. Either by incorrect implementation on my part or improper use, as Mtrw and User268396 suspect that this implementation is for time domain, not frequency (which is what I am using).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The generated C code is the recurrence relation which describes the filter behaviour in the time domain. Each index refers to a sample of the filtered input signal (what you might get from an ADC).

You 'broke' the code by:

1. Adding a 9th sample, where there should be none.
2. Somehow splitting the data in real/imaginary components (Q/I ?) which is not what the code is intended for.

Comment: Just like mtrw, you suggest the filter was intended for time domain use. The way I understood was that the author (RIP) provided a tool to build a filter, and the user is responsible for adjusting it to a particular situation. Maybe I just picked the wrong tool for the problem. 2nd paragraph: http://www.aip.de/groups/soe/local/numres/bookfpdf/f13-5.pdf

Comment: You can certainly adjust it any way you like but those `adjustments` change the frequency response by definition. You should read the next section on the definition of the recurrence relation for an IIR filter. The example C code being generated is derived from that. Now when you feed that data broken down into separate real & imaginary components (Q/I ?) you are taking numbers from one domain and pretending them to be valid/meaningful within another. In mathematics, that rarely works.

Comment: When you do study the recurrence relation one important thing to realise is that it describes an IIR filter. You can certainly do your filtering in the z-domain by computing the `X(z)` from your input x then applying the transfer function `H(z)` and finally reconstructing the equivalent y signal in the time domain from `Y(z)`. But note: ultimately it must be equivalent to the IIR filter in the time domain anyway. So you can also skip the whole z-transforms and do the filtering in the time domain. IIR filters typically have few terms, so this is much more convenient and easy to implement.

Comment: I don't know why it won't let me refer to your name with @... but I certainly understand your consideration, as I wasn't really aware that filters coming from the referred tool were supposed to be used in time. Since I will be doing work with phase too, and the fwFFT is already there, then maybe it is better if I just use one of these C++ implementations already available instead of reinventing the wheel. I will accept your comment as answer, due to the considerations you made here in the comments.